# Convert yymmdd10. to yyyymmddhhmmss in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a date value in yymmdd10. format (2017-08-07) and i want that to convert it to yyyymmddhhmmss. I've looked and tried various options but none of them worked for me. Can you suggest me someway to do it??

i used the DHMS function and datetime20 format but its not coming out in the desired format

POST1=DHMS(POST_DT,0,0,0); 
FORMAT POST1 DATETIME20.;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dhms()` should work, for example:

```
data _null_;
 date=input('2017-08-07',yymmdd10.);
 put date date9.;
 datetime=dhms(date,0,0,0);
 put datetime datetime20.;
 put datetime e8601dt20.;
run;
```

The problem might be that you're trying to supply the `dhms()` function with a string.  SAS dates and datetimes are not strings, no matter what format you apply to them.

You can use a variety of formats to output the date in ISO8601 notation, for example the extended notation above produces `2017-08-07T00:00:00`

Comment: Worked, Thanks David!!! the date field is in numeric format in my dataset, i've converted that to character first and used DHMS.. worked fantastic!!